# Why I get `ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: Unknown database` error when trying to use numbers and underline in database name?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

I am using ***ruby-2.2.4***, ***Rails 4.2.5*** and ***MySQL 5.7.16*** with gem **mysql2** in my Ruby on Rails application. I have created database with name `123_4` and set database name in `/config/database.yml`.

Why I am getting error `ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: Unknown database '1234'` when trying `rake db:migrate`?

If I try to run `rake db:create` database with name `1234` will be created.

If I use `123_abc4` for database name everything is fine.

my `database.yml` content:

```
production: 
   adapter: mysql2 
   database: 123_4 
   host: localhost 
   username: user 
   password: "pass" 
   encoding: utf8
```

Comment: can u show your database.yml ?

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Interesting. Could it be a bug in rails? How about opening an issue? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/new

Comment: I don't  know is it rails or, for example, active record bug. Could you reproduce it in your environment?

Comment: Check this [LINK](https://anandarajpandey.com/2015/05/10/mysql-naming-coding-conventions-tips-on-mysql-database/), it has some suggestions on naming conventions under **MySQL Name conventions general rules** header

Comment: @Abhi, thank you for link, but it is only convention without referring to MySQL documentation. Check Thanh Huynh answer if you are interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

[MySQL Schema Object Name](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

So you can use `123_abc4` because it contains letters.

If it only includes number, you will need to quote it: `'123_4'`

Comment: Thank you, @ThanhHuynh. Your answer clarify error reasons